# How best to capture referring URL in form using cookie?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies

I'm using the Wordpress Contact Form 7, setting a Cookie refurl using the Cookie Monster plugin. Using these tools (or any other), what is the easiest way to set a cookie that captures the referring URL and then adds this to a hidden field in a Contact Us form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Let's say that the cookie is called `"refurl"`

You can access it using:

```
var refURL = $.cookie("test");
```

You can append an element to your form by selecting it and adding the input to it. Let's say the `id` of your form is `ContactUsForm` :

```
var $el = $("<input />").attr("type","hidden").attr("value",refURL);
$("#ContactUsForm").append($el);
```

Comment: Is adding the jquery cookie plugin to wordpress as easy as adding the jquery cookie folder to the js directory in Wordpress?

Comment: It's exactly like adding any other script file to WP :)